# Close Window and open a new one in Python with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qt4, qt5

I'm new to PyQt5 and want to code a small programm

I designed two Windows in QT Designer and convertet them into a py Script.
Afterwards i merged both into one file (maybe my attempt is totaly wrong - so pls correct me)

When the program starts I get a small Window with some Radio Buttons and OK and Cancel.

I want to start another Window by clicking on OK. (This works fine)
My problem is, that the initial Window stays active in Background. (How can I close only the initial window? all my attempts have closed the whole programm. I do not know what I have to change?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CLASS_WELCOME(object):
    def setupUi(self, Welcome):
        Welcome.setObjectName("Welcome")
        Welcome.resize(204, 215)
        Welcome.setWindowTitle("Welcome")
        Welcome.setWhatsThis("")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Welcome)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 180, 191, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Welcome)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 151, 131))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 116, 22))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 116, 22))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 116, 22))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 116, 22))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Welcome)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Welcome)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.onOK)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Welcome.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Welcome)
        self.Gui = CLASS_GUI()


    def retranslateUi(self, Welcome):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Welcome", "blue"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Welcome", "green"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Welcome", "red"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Welcome", "yellow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Welcome", "Mensch aergere dich nicht!"))

    def onOK(self):
        MenschUi = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        MenschUi.ui = CLASS_GUI()
        MenschUi.ui.setupUi(MenschUi)
        MenschUi.exec_()



class CLASS_GUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, MenschUi):
        MenschUi.setObjectName("MenschUi")
        MenschUi.resize(640, 485)
        self.Abbrechen = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(MenschUi)
        self.Abbrechen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 450, 341, 32))
        self.Abbrechen.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.Abbrechen.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.Abbrechen.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.Abbrechen.setObjectName("Abbrechen")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(MenschUi)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 531, 431))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.Spieler = QtWidgets.QLabel(MenschUi)
        self.Spieler.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 66, 17))
        self.Spieler.setObjectName("Spieler")
        self.Computer = QtWidgets.QLabel(MenschUi)
        self.Computer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 66, 17))
        self.Computer.setObjectName("Computer")
        self.LCDSpieler = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(MenschUi)
        self.LCDSpieler.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 21, 23))
        self.LCDSpieler.setDigitCount(1)
        self.LCDSpieler.setObjectName("LCDSpieler")
        self.LCDComputer = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(MenschUi)
        self.LCDComputer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 21, 23))
        self.LCDComputer.setDigitCount(1)
        self.LCDComputer.setObjectName("LCDComputer")
        self.wuerfeln = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MenschUi)
        self.wuerfeln.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 81, 27))
        self.wuerfeln.setObjectName("wuerfeln")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MenschUi)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 450, 491, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(MenschUi)
        self.Abbrechen.accepted.connect(MenschUi.accept)
        self.Abbrechen.rejected.connect(MenschUi.reject)
        self.wuerfeln.clicked.connect(MenschUi.open)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MenschUi)

    def retranslateUi(self, MenschUi):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MenschUi.setWindowTitle(_translate("MenschUi", "Mensch Aergere dich Nicht!"))
        self.Spieler.setText(_translate("MenschUi", "Spieler"))
        self.Computer.setText(_translate("MenschUi", "Computer"))
        self.wuerfeln.setText(_translate("MenschUi", "wuerfeln"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Welcome = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = CLASS_WELCOME()
    ui.setupUi(Welcome)
    Welcome.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create a new window in PyQt without it having a parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879261/cannot-create-a-new-window-in-pyqt-without-it-having-a-parent)

Comment: It is a mistake to merge the files generated by pyuic. You must **never** edit these files. See the [pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) for examples of how to do things properly.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly calling self.hide() in the beginning of the method onOK would do the job. (Untested)
You could lookup some Methods [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide).

Comment: I testet it with self.hide() but this also hides the second window

Comment: You can't do `self.hide()` in the OP's example, because `self` is not a widget.

Comment: @JosefGschwentner. Calling `hide()` or `close()` on the first window is the right thing to do. However, it will only work properly if the second window is top-level (i.e. if it doesn't have a parent).