# Pyqt4, can not open new window in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am a greener of python. I am trying to create an application here is my all of code. The application will work if data are match successfully then it will show another window.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os
import MySQLdb as mdb


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setObjectName("host")
        self.le.setText("Host")

        self.pb = QPushButton()
        self.pb.setObjectName("connect")
        self.pb.setText("Connect") 

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(self.pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.button_click)
        self.setWindowTitle("Learning")

    def button_click(self):
        # shost is a QString object
        shost = self.le.text()
        if shost:

           s_h = "127.0.0.1"
           s_n = "root"
           s_p = ""
           s_d = "code"

           s_cn = mdb.connect(s_h, s_n, s_p, s_d)

           cursor = s_cn.cursor()

           query = "SELECT * FROM  `ac` WHERE  `acc` = %s "
           re = cursor.execute(query,(shost,))

           if re:

               ex = Example()
               ex.show()                

           else:
              print "no"




class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def run(self):
        os.startfile("hyt.exe")
    def initUI(self):

        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)


        btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())
        btn1.move(20, 20)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.run)

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(150, 20)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Python Script')



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

But my problem is when i press button then it will be show Example() window . but here when i press button then it show the window for 1 second so how can i fix it ?

```
 if re:

               ex = Example()
               ex.show()                

           else:
              print "no"
```

Comment: Keep a reference: `self.ex = Example(); self.ex.show()`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061178/pyqt-window-closes-after-launch

Comment: And, depending on what you want to do with the window, this might also be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879261/cannot-create-a-new-window-in-pyqt-without-it-having-a-parent

Comment: Thank's @ekhumoro work it successfully